# split big table into two joined view

Tags: postgresql, view, table

i have a big postgres db with single table for product and attribute but i want two view of one with product and one with attribute.

for example now i have

**tb_products**

```
iditem | name | attributes
-----------------------
1      | art1 | a
2      | art1 | b    
3      | art1 | c
4      | art1 | d
```

what i need is

**vs_product**

```
iditem | name 
-----------------------
1      | art1
```

**vs_attrib**

```
iditem |  attributes
-----------------------
1      | a
1      | b   
1      | c
1      | d
```

what i have tried is something like this and it seem to work, but is too slow when extractiong attributes

vs_product

```
SELECT
Min(.tb_products."id") AS "Product ID",
FROM
tb_products
GROUP BY
tb_products.item
```

vs_attrib

```
SELECT
a1."id" AS "oldid",
(
SELECT MIN
    ( a2."id" )  
FROM
    tb_products a2
WHERE 
    a1.name = a2.name
GROUP BY
    a1.name 
) AS "newid"
FROM
tb_products AS a1
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is the meaning of the `id` column in your example?

Comment: Why id=1 was taken from source table to first view and why another 3 values were ignored?

Comment: *too slow* For 1st query create index `tb_products (item, id)`.2nd query must be re-writed to avoid correlated subq in output list (use window function).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i hope this is ok now

Comment: @Akina first query is fast only the second, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

> only the second, can you be more specific?

For second view test

```
CREATE VIEW vs_attrib 
AS
SELECT MIN(iditem) OVER (PARTITION BY name) iditem, attributes
FROM tb_products
```

Index `tb_products (name, iditem)` may increase view's performance.

Comment: only vs_attrib query is slow

Comment: @webbo The code was given for it (view**2**). The name edited.

Comment: it works perferct!! very fast